# IPad not supporting target ="_self"

Tags: javascript, ipad, uri, lync, skype-for-business

I am trying to use Skype for business URIs to open on an IPad from safari browser. But whenever I click on link its not showing popup for opening Skype for business app. It's working fine for chrome and other browsers on IPad, but not for safari. Here is the code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <script>
function myfunction() {
   window.open("sip:","_self")
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">IM for desktop</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is how  can I open my sip uri in same window in safari browser